# How to change the tickness of shadow of conatiner based on the spread in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I need to create a shadow for container but the shadow color needs to be changed when spread.

```
Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  spreadRadius: 12,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                   color: Color(0xffEBEBEB),
                                 // // color: Color(0xff1E1E1E),
                                 //   spreadRadius: 25,
                                   blurRadius: 14,
                                  //offset: Offset(0.0, 1),
                                )
                                
                              ]
                          ),
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: 0.5,
                        ),
```

I tried many ways but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the background color of the Drawer?

Comment: it's not a drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add shadow, you have to add decoration as a parent of column widget. not as a separator.

Simple way you can wrap your column with `Material` and set the `elevation`

```
 Material(
  elevation:20,
  shadowColor: Colors.grey,
  child: Column(
 ....
```

---

Another option is by setting the shadow manually. Setting the `offset` for specific position of shadow:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color:Colors.white,
    boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
      offset: Offset(-12, 0),
      color: Colors.grey,
      blurRadius: 5,
    )
  ]),
  child: Column(
....
```

`offset(-12,0)` will placed the shadow only on the left side.

Result:

[image]

or you can customize the position of shadow.

- only left : `Offset(-x,0)`
- top and left : `Offset(-x,-y)`
- top and right : `Offset(x,-y)`
- bottom and left : `Offset(-x,y)`
- etc

Try demo here:  https://dartpad.dev/?id=ebad3affe59160e1070642da95d1ab69

Comment: i tried but didnt get that exact output

Comment: wrap widget parent of "News Summary" with the container and shadow

Comment: I tried like this..my shadow color is  #000000, with 14% opacity.I gave that one bt didn't look like exact design

Comment: can you provide minimal reproduce code? so i can see same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the spread and increase the blur:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          spreadRadius: 0,
          offset: Offset(0, 0),
          color: Color(0xffEBEBEB),
          blurRadius: 20,
        ),
      ],
  ),
  height: double.infinity,
  width: 0.5,
),
```

You probably have to adjust the color since I could barely see the shadow while testing.